# Rails 4 How to edit an object from a different model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, link-to

How can I edit an object in model A from a model B view? The models are associated. I have tried hardcoding the object_id ( link_to 'Edit' edit_a_path(2) ) and it works of course. But how can I do it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Model A is `User` and model b is `Post` and a user `has_many` posts then you will be able to access a Users posts like so:

```
# In controller
@user = User.find(params[:id])

# In view

# if user has_many posts
<% @user.posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
<% end %>

# if user has_one post
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@user.post) %>
```

This might not reflect your models though so comment if not.

You should take a look at [the rails association guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) or for a more in depth understanding do the [rails tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book). It's awesome.